# Create a desired JSON format using data stored in PHP

Tags: php, json, data-structures

So I have a bunch of arrays inside which I have all the data I require to pass to a third party app. Problem is that they need it in a specific JSON format, and I do not have an idea how I can do that. The data format they require is like:

```
{
   "appData" : {
      "appKey" : "blah blah",
      "synth" : {
         "synth1" : {
            "mono" : [
               {
                  "monoId" : "529",
                  "templates" : [
                     {
                        "monoSequenceMap" : [
                           {
                              "map" : {
                                 "X" : "3",
                                 "Y" : "1"
                              },
                              "position" : {
                                 "scale" : "1",
                                 "x1" : "100",
                                 "x2" : "150",
                                 "y1" : "2000",
                                 "y2" : "2500"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "map" : {
                                 "X" : "2",
                                 "Y" : "4"
                              },
                              "position" : {
                                 "scale" : "1",
                                 "x1" : "200",
                                 "x2" : "550",
                                 "y1" : "1000",
                                 "y2" : "1500"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "map" : {
                                 "X" : "3",
                                 "Y" : "3"
                              },
                              "position" : {
                                 "scale" : "1.5",
                                 "x1" : "300",
                                 "x2" : "750",
                                 "y1" : "1750",
                                 "y2" : "1800"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "map" : {
                                 "X" : "4",
                                 "Y" : "1"
                              },
                              "position" : {
                                 "scale" : "1.5",
                                 "x1" : "680",
                                 "x2" : "790",
                                 "y1" : "1950",
                                 "y2" : "1850"
                              }
                           }
                        ],
                        "templateId" : "01_A_19"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "synthId" : "XXXXXXXXXX"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I just want some pointers on how to convert the data I have into this JSON string. I think I need to use `json_encode`. Should I create a new class called 'appData' class then create each object/array inside it? or should I just write a string in this format into a text file?

My problem is that I cannot wrap my head around having all these objects inside objects thing...like for e.g, in the JSON synth is an object which contains synth1, synth2 etc which will be objects which in turn will have mono which will be an array of objects...And I am not sure how to tackle that..

Any pointers is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are your arrays multidimensional? Like:

```
$array = array(
    "data_table_1" => array(
        "item1" => "Item 1",
        "item2" => "Item 2"
    ),
    "data_table_1" => array(
        "item1" => "Item 1",
        "item2" => "Item 2"
    )
);
```

If so, all you have to use is use json_encode and that will do all the encoding for you:

```
$json = @json_encode($array);
```

==== Edit ====
arrays do not have to be multidimensional. Even an array with a single key => value will work. Just be sure you have keys for values, so they're registered correctly.